# ¿consulta MYSQL agrupando campos

Tags: mysql

tengo esta tabla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estoy haciendo una vista donde me muestre el lote_ae, fk_referencia_ae y el total cantidad_ae.

es decir de los cuatro datos que tengo en mi tabla el resultado deberia ser este:
**

```
**resultado 1:**
lote_ae:123456
fk_referencia_ae: E0038
tl_cantidad:100
**resultado 2:**
lote_ae:123456
fk_referencia_ae: I0030
tl_cantidad:114
**resultado 3:**
lote_ae:203305
fk_referencia_ae: I0030
tl_cantidad:234
```

**

no sé si es entendible mi ejemplo, lo que esta haciendo es sumar **cantidad_ae** donde **lote_ae** sea igual a **lote_ae** igual y **fk_referencia_ae** tambien sea igual a **fk_referencia_ae**, y los deberia agrupa tanto por **lote_ae** como por **fk_referencia_ae**. ya que si **lote_ae** es diferente entonces la suma de **cantidad_ae** aplica solo para todos los **fk_referencia_ae** que correspondan a ese **lote_ae**.

si tengo tres lote_ae iguales y tres fk_referencia_ae iguales, el resultado va ser 1 porque todos son iguales.

si tengo tres lote_ae iguales  y dos fk_referencia_ae iguales, el resultado va ser 2 porque un fk_referencia_ae es diferente.

si tengo dos lote_ae iguales y tres fk_referencia_ae iguales, el resultado va ser dos 2 porque un lote es diferente.

no sé si me hago entender.

intenten con esta consulta:

```sql
select 
fk_referencia_ae,
lote_ae,
sum(cantidad_ae)
from 
  control_salida_empaque 
where 
  lote_ae=lote_ae 
group by fk_referencia_ae;
```

pera esta no me esta tomando encuenta si aunque sea igual fk_referencia_ae el lote es diferente.

Comment: Hola. Por favor, por la respuesta como respuesta, abajo. No la pongas en la pregunta. Después puedes marcarla como aceptada, así otros sabrán cuál es la solución

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RESPUESTA**
FALTABA AGRUPAR POR fk_referencia_ae y lote_ae.

asi quedaria la consulta MYSQL.

```sql
SELECT
lote_ae,
fk_referencia_ae,
sum(cantidad_ae)
from
  control_salida_empaque 
where
  fk_referencia_ae=fk_referencia_ae and 
  lote_ae=lote_ae 
GROUP BY lote_ae, fk_referencia_ae;
```